# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module calling js from Python (Dash)

Tags: javascript, module, three.js, plotly-dash

I'm trying to call the example of three.js from fireship-io (Youtube channel) to make an animated background on my Python dash app based on the scrolling of the user. The Js script continuously calls a function that updates the rotation of objects and the position of a camera.

I installed node and I can run the js on its own but when I call it from my python scripts it throws an error at line 1. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js?m=1658899110.9005847:1:1)`. It cannot import `style.css`, but the dash app can see the css because the font is the one defined in it.

How can I solve this error? Is there a way to specify "type":"module" in Dash when running a js?

Note: The js is called automatically by dash since it's in the assets directory. I added `"type":"module"` in package.json but it still gives me an error.

main.js:

```
import './style.css';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

...
```

app.py:

```
app = Dash(__name__)
server = app.server


app.layout = html.Div(children=[
 ...
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "three-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.128.0"
  }
}
```

Root folder:

```
app.py
assets/
  - main.js
  - package.json
  - style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

If this link: [Adding Your Own CSS and JavaScript to Dash Apps](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources)
is anything to go by then your css would be included automatically by Dash if it's in the correct folder.

So you can probably skip the import in the main.js file

If you look at the link above again and scroll to 'Adding External CSS/JavaScript'.

You could try to skip the import in the `main.js` file and add this to your python file:

```py
external_scripts = [
  'https://threejs.org/build/three.js'
]
```

Something similar would probably have to be done for the 'OrbitControls'.

Comment: You're right but I still get the same error for line 2 at `import * as THREE from 'three';`

Comment: If you try to rename the `main.js` to `main.mjs` what happens then?

Comment: By skipping the import part, I could make it work by adding 

`external_scripts = ['assets/three.js']

app = Dash(__name__, external_scripts=external_scripts, assets_ignore='main.js')`

and calling `import dash_defer_js_import as dji` and `dji.Import(src="assets/main.js")`  after every variable in the script is initialized. However, if I want to include a module such as FBXLoader (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js), I still cna't because of the imports in the beggining. Is there a way to specify if a script is a module in dash?